# predict() does not take sarima object in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am doing a Time Series Analysis on gasoline demand.
the data is from package TSDL

I will show the relevant code below:

```
library(tsdl)
options(warn=-1)
tsdl_gasdemand <- subset(tsdl, "Sales")
X_t <- tsdl_gasdemand[[1]]
plot(X_t,main = "Monthly gasoline demand Ontario gallon millions 1960 – 1975",
     ylab = "")
```

Then Box-Cox test and differenced which give PACF/ACF

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(diffs, lag.max=50, main=expression(nabla[12]~(X[t]^{BC})))
pacf(diffs, lag.max=60, main=expression(nabla[12]~(X[t]^{BC})))
```

[ACF/PACF of differenced data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK6fY.png)

then I select model SARIMA(3,0,0)x(1,1,0)<sub>12</sub>

I used function :
`model4 <- sarima(xdata=train.bc, p=3, d=0, q=0, P=1, D=1, Q=0, S=12, details = F)`

There is three more models with different parameters choice but they have higher AICC value so they are not displayed.

And Here is the key issue, This sarima() fits model with a constant,

```
Coefficients:
          ar1     ar2     ar3     sar1  constant
      -0.2432  0.0356  0.5622  -0.4113    1.6712
s.e.   0.0692  0.0735  0.0734   0.0812    0.0970
```

This results in error message of predict() I later use to predict time series value

```
pred.demand <- predict(model4$fit, n.ahead = 12)

Error in eval(expr, p) : object 'constant' not found
```

I have tried using

```
SARIMA <- arima(train.bc, order=c(3,0,0), method="ML",
      seasonal = list(order = c(1,1,0), period = 12))
```

to avoid the `constant` issue

But the model generated by this function has a residual PACF of peak at lag 5 which is not good, [Residual ACF/PACF by arima fun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rlnq.png)

I have also tried `sarima.for` from the `astsa` package, it generates prediction plot but can't show the viewers the calculation steps.

I think there is two way to solve the issue,

1.let `predict()` know where the `constant` is

2.add `constant` to the model generated by `arima()`

However, I don't know the solution to either of them.

All suggestion welcomed, thank you very much for your time!

If you need more code to reproduce the result please leave a comment.